# How do I align a kendo UI window with another element on the page?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, alignment, kendo-window

I have a link which, when clicked, opens a kendo UI window. I'd like to align the window with the link. My current logic to do so is:

```
        kendoWindow.setOptions({
            position: {
                top: link.position().top + link.height(),
                left: link.position().left
            }
        });
```

This works in the common case, but doesn't handle things like flowing off the page. Is there a better/more robust way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at their Tooltip (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tooltip/template) widget?  Perhaps it might be more appropriate / easier to use for your user case.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing built-in; there is a method that handles this for popups, but appropriating this for the window will be more work than implementing it yourself.

Just calculate whether the viewport has enough space for the desired position plus width or height of your window. If it doesn't, adjust the position accordingly.